# Safari VoiceOver SVG announces tags inside `<svg />` as separate images

Tags: html, svg, safari, accessibility, voiceover

I have an `<svg />` element and when I navigate to it in Safari using VoiceOver, the VO announces 6 different images instead of one. Chrome works fine and this element gets announces as an "Unlabelled image":

```
<svg aria-labelledby="imageLabel-10" class="foo" viewBox="0 -60 577 586">
   <title id="sometitle-10"></title>
   <defs>
      <polygon id="someid" points="1 2 3">
      </polygon>
      <path d="M.123" id="someOtherId">
      </path>
      <mask fill="white" id="oneMoreId">
         <use xlink:href="#someHred">
         </use>
      </mask>
   </defs>
   <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g style="transform: translateY(-22.0061px); transform-origin: 396.328px 301.186px;">
         <path d="M225" fill="#F75647" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="translate(0, 0)">
         </path>
      </g>
      <g mask="url(#someHref)">
         <image height="461" transform="scale(1.1)" width="693" x="60" xlink:href="//cuteCDNPath.jpg" y="-10" style="transform: scale(1.05339); transform-origin: 286.5px 220.5px;">
         </image>
         <use fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.01" xlink:href="#someOtherHref" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;">
         </use>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

macOS Mojave 10.14.6
Safari 13.0.5

Answer (score 1):

[According to Deque](https://www.deque.com/blog/creating-accessible-svgs/) (specifically strategy #5), `<svg>` tags require a `role` attribute to be set to `img`. I am not 100% sure this is the right solution, but adding `role="img"` did fix my problem.

```
    <svg 
      aria-labelledby="imageLabel-10"
      class="..."
      role="img" <!-- this was the missing attribute -->
      viewBox="..."
    >
    ...
    </svg>
```